# Show that a square integer cannot be put in the form 4k+2

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let a² be any integer. Show that a² cannot be put in the form 4k+2

Answer (score 4):

All integer can be represented as $2n$ or $2n+1$   $$(2n)^2\equiv0\pmod4$$

$$(2n+1)^2\equiv1\pmod4$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a$ is even. Then $a=2n$, $a^2=4n$ is divisible by $4$. Suppose instead $a$ is odd. Then $a=(2n+1)$, $a^2=4(n^2+n)+1$ leaves remainder $1$ on division by $4$. So only $4k$ and $4k+1$ are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can represent $a = 2i $ or $a = 2i+1$, then $a^2 = 4i^2$ or $4i(i + 1) + 1$. With redefinition: $4*k$ or $4l + 1$

Answer (score 0):

All integers have one of the following forms: $4k, 4k+1, 4k+2, 4k+3$. For each case, what form does the square have?

Answer (score 0):

if we suppose that there is an $a^2\equiv 2\pmod 4$. Then $a^2$=4k+2 ,whence it's even. From Fermat's theorem we can say that $a^2\equiv a \equiv0\pmod 2$. So 
$a^2\equiv a*a \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ which is a contradiction.